how to make flowbite react dropdown to fill the whole width of his parent div
I tried to put the w-full on the label of the dropdown, and also to give dropdown 100% width with css. I want it also to be responsive so it can match the parent div properly without seems not good
<div className="col-span-12 sm:col-span-3 mt-4 w-full">
  <Dropdown
    arrowIcon={false}
    inline
    label={
      <div
        className="flex items-center justify-between px-1 py-2 w-full"
        style={{
          border: '1px solid #E7ECF5',
          background: '#FFFFFF',
          borderRadius: '14px',
          opacity: 1,
        }}
      >
        <span className="dropdown-span text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 cursor-pointer">
          {insuranceOptions.find((option) => option.id === selectedInsuranceId)?.name || 'Insurance'}
        </span>
        <GoChevronDown size={20} />
      </div>
    }
  >
    <Dropdown.Item onClick={resetFilters} className={!selectedInsuranceId ? 'bg-gray-200' : ''}>
      All Insurances
    </Dropdown.Item>
    {insuranceOptions.map((option) => (
      <Dropdown.Item
        key={option.id}
        onClick={() => handleInsuranceChange(option.id)}
        className={selectedInsuranceId === option.id ? 'bg-gray-200' : ''}
      >
        {option.name}
     </Dropdown.Item>
    ))}
  </Dropdown>
</div>

